# Is it possible to make SP/Function as private ones?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am using Microsoft SQL 2005 server. I have created several SP and Functions in TSQL. After more than one year's development, the number of SP/Functions have grown dramatically. Only a few of SP/Functions are used as scheduled jobs or triggers, and most of them are used internally(I mean they are called by SP/Functions in jobs and triggers).

With the number of SP/Functions growing, it is very hard to manage them in our SQL server. It is hard for other developer/DBAs to know their dependency and usages. I would like to keep all the dependent SP/Functions as private ones just like ones in PL/SQL's packages. I could rewrite them in CLR but customized CLR is not allowed in our SQL server.

Any way to limit SP/Function's usage scope, i.e., limit them as private in a "package"? Not sure if SQL 2008 have any features to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005 (onwards), you can use [Schemas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190387.aspx) for this purpose, BUT it does have security chaining implications.

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not yet have a 'package' equivalent, though I believe that this is something which has been requested often.

Comment: Is this 'package' available on SQL 2008?

Comment: Nope, no 'packages' in 2008 either.

Comment: @David Chu: schema's are available on SQL 2005 onwards

Comment: My understanding of schema is that if a SP is supposed as public for a user, then the dependency SPs are also to be public to that user. If that's the case, it does not resolve my issue of limiting one SP as public but others as privates.

Comment: David Chu: It *can* work that way, but that's not normally how you would choose to do it.  Normally, the SP's in the schema would run with the rights of the schema *owner* (and not the SP caller) which you can setup to give the schema.SP's access to other schemas and resources, including other SP's that the users cannot see or touch by themselves.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't it ironic? The very tool that was supposed to help you reduce complexity creates more. I used SP last about 2 years ago when I created the first version of a blogging website that I was making. They caused me a lot of heartache cause I couldn't fit them well in the scheme of things (my C# code).

So finally I got rid of them and took all my SP code back to C#. That made things easier to organizer.

Now I may use Views, but I don't use SPs any more.